# phpbb3 Android web application upload files / photos

Tags: android, file, upload, phpbb3

I made a web Android application for my website / forum phpbb3. Everything is fine, the only problem I have is I can't upload files/photos. Even if I press the button for browsing my phone, nothing happens.

What can I do?

Comment: I found the solution! But, if I choose to take a picture instantly  the photo upload to forum but if I choose from the gallery I have a message " image%163030 not allowed. "

Comment: I found the problem openFileChooser doesn't working with kitkat 4.4. But I can't found solution. It is working like a charm with 4.1 android.

Comment: Part of manifest xml is: <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".ShowWebView" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>